# How rename files in a directory using python?

Tags: python, operating-system, rename, glob

The python script I am writing should be able to work in any folder I put in.
I have to find all the .avi files. If the file name ends with cropped.avi then I have to rename it and save it as .avi, without the word cropped.

```
import os
import glob

os.getcwd()
glob.glob('*.avi')
directory = glob.glob('*.avi')

for directory:
    if i.endswith("cropped.avi"):
         os.rename("cropped.avi",".avi")
```

I think my code is missing something and I don't know what to do!!

Comment: do you need 'for directory' to change to 'for i in directory'?

Comment: why do you do `glob.glob()` twice?

Comment: or `os.getcwd()` without assigning to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop syntax was incorrect. This works:

```
import os
import glob

directory = glob.glob('*.avi')
for i in directory:
    if i.endswith("cropped.avi"):
         os.rename("cropped.avi",".avi")
```